# What is wrong with my listener?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, repaint

I have created the interface gui and added the buttons. But now I am stuck with the "Steady" button. When I click it I want to the circle "light bulb" to change color from yellow to orange.

What am I doing wrong in my code and when I press the "Steady" button nothing is happening?

```
/**
 * Created by Metallion on 30/03/2015.
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BelishaBeacon {

    public class Drawing extends JPanel {
        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            //creating the shapes
            Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);
            //drawing the shapes
            Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2.draw(ball);
            g2.draw(box1);
            g2.draw(box2);
            g2.draw(box3);
            g2.draw(box4);
            g2.draw(box5);
            g2.draw(box6);
            //coloring the shapes
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(box1);
            g2.fill(box3);
            g2.fill(box5);
            g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2.fill(ball);
        }
    }

    public class changeColors extends JPanel {
        private boolean choseColor = false;
        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;

        public void changeColor(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            if (!choseColor) {
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
            }
        }

        public void changeColor() { choseColor = false; }
    }


    public BelishaBeacon() {
        //Creation of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 570);
        frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();
        final changeColors colorinG = new changeColors();
        JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
        final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        colorinG.changeColor();
                        colorinG.repaint();
                    }
                });

        //Positioning
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
        controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);


        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(shapes);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new BelishaBeacon();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is OK, but it would be better if you would reduce it to a [smaller example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might even find the issue along the way.

Comment: Ok, will keep that in mind for the next one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to add handling logic to your `Drawing` Swing component, e.g.**:

1. add method to your `Drawing` to change the color
2. modify the `paintComponent(Graphics)` according to the first step

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.geom.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

   public class BelishaBeacon {

       public class Drawing extends JPanel {

           private int x = 125;
           private int y = 80;
           private boolean changeColors = false;

           public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
               super.paintComponent(g);
               Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
               //creating the shapes
               Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
               Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
               Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
               Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
               Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
               Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);
               //drawing the shapes
               Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
               g2.draw(ball);
               g2.draw(box1);
               g2.draw(box2);
               g2.draw(box3);
               g2.draw(box4);
               g2.draw(box5);
               g2.draw(box6);
               //coloring the shapes
               g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
               g2.fill(box1);
               g2.fill(box3);
               g2.fill(box5);
               g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
               g2.fill(ball);

               if (changeColors) {
                   g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                   g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
               }

               changeColors = false;
           }

           public void changeColors() {
               changeColors = true;
               repaint();
           }
       }

       public BelishaBeacon() {
           //Creation of frame
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();
           frame.setSize(350, 570);
           frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
           frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
           final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

           JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
           final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
           jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                   new ActionListener() {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                           shapes.changeColors();
                       }
                   });

           //Positioning
           JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
           controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
           controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
           controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);

           frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           frame.add(shapes);

           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.setVisible(true);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new BelishaBeacon();
       }
   }
   ```